# Configure Rpi 3 for ethernet router with jessie

Tags: pi-3, networking, linux, raspbian-jessie, ethernet

I am configuring my Rpi 3 as ethernet router. I have used dnsmasq for configuring dns and dhcp server. The configuration files are given below.

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.2.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.2.0
    broadcast 192.168.2.255

up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

/et/dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=eth1 #listen only to interface eth1
listen-address=192.168.2.1 # listen on
# Bind to the interface to make sure we aren't sending things
# elsewhere
bind-interfaces
server=8.8.8.8 # Forward DNS requests to Google DNS
domain-needed # Don't forward short names
# Never forward addresses in the non-routed address spaces.
bogus-priv
# Assign IP addresses between 192.168.2.2 and 192.168.2.100 with a
# 12 hours lease time
dhcp-range=192.168.2.2,192.168.2.100,12h
```

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
vm.swappiness=1
vm.min_free_kbytes = 8192
```

At last iptables configuration for seting nat is given below

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -t nat -F

#Connect a LAN to the internet
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

#forward only the packets that are associated with an established #connection
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#forward all packets from eth1 to eth0
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat"
```

These configuration perfectly works for older wheezy versions and jessie lite version too but in jessie full version( 2017-08-16) its not working.

When i configured the files above, rpi won't get connected to my external router (router and rpi are connected through a lan cable). I think this is because configuration for eth0 is changed when i configured the files as above.

In Raspbian jessie version, i don't know where to configure the network interfaces. Also they shipped with inbuilt bind9 and dhcpcd, hence is there any conflict with dnsmasq server.

`sudo service dnsmasq status` throws an exit-code error.

Can anyone please help me to solve this?

How to configure Rpi 3 with raspbian jessie for the ethernet router?

Answer (score 1):

I think i've read somewhere that you should not modify `/etc/network/interfaces` anymore.

If you want to set up static IP's you should modify `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

```
interface eth1
static ip_address 192.168.2.1/24
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` And before `exit 0;` paste:

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

It works for me on Stretch and I've been following [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) tutorial and using [**dhcpcd method**](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/56918) ( ***SUPER IMPORTANT FOR Stretch VERSION*** )

That's my guess. Provide the error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

In `etc/network/interfaces`, you don't bring up eth0 automatically -

`auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp`

Add in `auto eth0` to make sure that eth0 will actually come up and get an IP address, so it should look like this -

`auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp`

Also the same with `eth1`, make sure you bring that up automatically.

Raspbian Stretch uses `dhcpcd.conf` to configure the networking unless they are configured in `/etc/network/interfaces`